# Get Facebook Post Reaction Count posted in a Facebook page you do not owned

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

So I want to get the reaction count of a facebook post from a facebook page I do not owned or I'm not the admin.

I tried the Graph API Explorer but I can't find some of the permissions I think I need like read_insights. Is there any other way to do what I want to do?

Comment: You would need the Page Public Content Access feature approved for your app. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/features-reference/page-public-content-access/